# Blazor WASM Authentication Static Web App

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor, azure-static-web-app

I've got a problem which I quite don't understand yet (used doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) , if I try to **login**, it **works** on the Static Web App (**SWA**) and **locally**.
[image: locally]
[image: SWA]

but when I try to **logout**,
**locally** it **works** and on the **SWA** it **doesn't**.

[image: locally]
[image: SWA]

Anyone has an idea what the problem is?
Screenshots for reference:

Portal app registration:
[image: POrtal]

appsettings.json

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT-ID",
    "ClientId": "CLIENT-ID",
    "ValidateAuthority": true
  }
}
```

staticwebapp.config.json

```
{
  "networking": {
    "allowedIpRanges": [
      "IP/MASK"
    ]
  }
}
```

Program.cs

```
public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IProductService<ProductA,InsuredPerson>, ProductAService>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IProductService<ProductB,InsuredPerson>, ProductBService>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDownloadService,DownloadService>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUploadService, UploadService>();
            builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(new[] { typeof(ServiceMappingProfile)});
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
    
            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
            builder.Services.AddLocalization();


            builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes
                    .Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read");
                options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
            });
            

            var host = builder.Build();

            CultureInfo culture;

            var js = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>();

            var result = await js.InvokeAsync<string>("blazorCulture.get");

            if (result != null)
            {
                culture = new CultureInfo(result);
            }
            else
            {
                culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                await js.InvokeVoidAsync("blazorCulture.set", "en-US");
            }
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;

            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
```

App.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated != true)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p role="alert">You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check these points while configuring:

•   Install the NuGet package `Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal` to authenticate your application using NuGet Manager.

•   While Enabling  the authentication by injecting the [Authorize] attribute to the **Razor pages** (Counter.razor and FetchData.razor).Also add reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization

```
@attribute [Authorize]
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
```

In **LoginDisplay.razor** , check the below code for login and logout

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject SignOutSessionStateManager SignOutManager

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-link" @onclick="BeginLogout">
            Log out
        </button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="authentication/login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {
    private async Task BeginLogout(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        await SignOutManager.SetSignOutState();
        Navigation.NavigateTo("authentication/logout");
    }
}
```

Pages/Authentication.razor

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

**Reference** : [Using Azure Active Directory to Secure a Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App (code-maze.com)](https://code-maze.com/using-azure-active-directory-to-secure-a-blazor-webassembly-standalone-app/)

Workarounds that you may try:

Try 1:
Clear all the cache , try login and logout.

Try 2:
If all these are set properly and still facing the issue , Try with setting Redirect type to Web instead of SPA.

For example:

[image]

Try 3:
Include "post_logout_redirect_uri": "https://localhost:5001/authentication/logout-callback",  In the json file of app where the redirect uri is mentioned
And give that url in logout url in portal in the app's registration screen:

> - select Authentication in the menu.
> - In the Logout URL section, set it to https://    localhost:5001/authentication/logout-callback

Comment: Hey @kavyasaraboju-MT,

thank you for this informative post, 

(Try 2) If I try to set the platform on Web from SPA (Static Web App) it doesn't work. As mentioned it works locally completely fine, but on the SPA the logout gets a 404 message.

I'll edit my appsettigs.json and staticwebapp.congig.json into my question.

Comment: it works now and I am not sure, if its due to adding 
"navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "index.html"
  }
into the staticwebapp.config.json